# Get Type of Controller that is being created

Tags: autofac

I'm setting up logging in an MVC project. My class NLogLogger takes a parameter of type [Type]. Is there anyway that I can get autofac to instantiate the NLogLogger object passing in the type of the Controller that is currently being instantiated? In the code below, TTT needs to be the Type of the controller.

```
builder.Register(c => new NLogLogger(TTT)).As<ILogger>();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Thanks very much for your help.

Damien.

Comment: Still looking for an answer here. I played with the code below to see if the class could be accessed from IComponentContext (c)... but no luck. Still looking! :-)

builder.Register((c, t) =>
                {
                    return new NLogLogger(); 
                }).As<ILogger>();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to solve this in the same way as [the Log4NetIntegration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Log4NetIntegration) works. You set up a `Module` that listens in on every component preparation (when some instance is about to be created by the container) and supply the NLog logger for the component type.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that's exactly what I was after.
It's a nice piece of code. I'm very impressed with Autofac and am happy with my IoC container choice :-)

Comment: @PeterLillevold i am trying to implement this to my app but i couldn't. First of all LogManager.GetLogger(t) doesn't accept t parameter because of type. Is there any example of this implementation?

Comment: @bahadirarslan - the sample I pointed to is for log4net, not NLog. You will have to make your own implementation for NLog. I only suggested you use the sample as a starting point.